# How to merge a .DLL file into my VB Project

Tags: vb.net, dll, ilmerge

I am creating a video downloader and I have a .DLL file which helps me gather the video information from youtube etc. Now here lies the problem , when I run my program without the .DLL file it starts up an error screen and crashes, however when the .DLL file is included it works. Now, I want to know how to merge these 2 files (my program which is an .exe file & the .DLL file) into one .EXE file. I have searched through the web and have seen that many people recommend ILMERGE , however I cannot find any step by step instructions which explains how I do it. Thanks.

Comment: if you wrote the DLL just include the project into yours.  if you didnt, whether it can be merged depends on the type of DLL.  Is this MediaInfo.DLL?  (also, it is not a crime or a sin to deploy an EXE that needs, uses a DLL).

Comment: http://blog.risingperfection.com/2013/03/how-to-use-ilmerge-and-how-to-build-portable-applications.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers @Plutonix the .DLL is called VideoDownloaderDLL.dll which I have from an external source..

Comment: You don't "merge the DLL into your project". You distribute it with your application. Just deploy the DLL with your application. (A DLL, by definition, is a "Dynamic Link Library", which means it's designed to be loaded by your application dynamically when your app runs. If it was designed to be merged into your app, it would be a statically linked library instead.)

Comment: Definitely NOT a good idea to merge someone else's work into yours, in that case. (ESPECIALLY since it is not a separate distributable).

Comment: @ Plutonix I have permission using the .DLL file

Answer (score 0):

If you've referenced the DLL in your EXE all you need to do is copy it into the directory where your app is installed.